# Laravel Redis configuration

Tags: php, redis, laravel-5

I am currently creating an app with Laravel and Redis. Almost everything is working fine. I extended the Authentication as explained in the documentation, users can subscribe, login, logout ... I can create content and everything is stored in Redis.
But I have one issue. I can't run commands like "**php artisan route:list**", I have an error message : "**[InvalidArgumentException] Database [redis] not configured.**".

Th question is, is there anything special to do to make Artisan commands work when you set Redis as you database ? (basic configurations explained in the documention have been done and almost everything else is working fine).

Config:
In config/database.php I have:

return [
...
    'default' => 'redis',
...
'redis' => [

```
    'cluster' => false,
    //'connection' => 'default',
    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 7,
    ],

],
```

...

PS : You have the same error when you try to access the /password/email (password reset url).

InvalidArgumentException in DatabaseManager.php line 246:
Database [redis] not configured.

Comment: The default driver searches in the `connections` array, there is no support for Redis there. `Currently Laravel supports four database systems: MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, and SQL Server.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483117/robert) says in the comments, it looks like there is this error because there is no support for Redis as database for laravel.