# Eloquent model for Redis

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5

I have installed Laravel 5.1 with Redis and when I have tested it, I got error `Database [redis] not configured.`.
Than I have tested it from routes using Redis instead of Eloquent model:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    Redis::set("key", "testValue");
    return Redis::get("key");
});
```

And success...

After this i have searched and founded just it - 
[Laravel Redis configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154422/laravel-redis-configuration)

> there is no support for Redis there

What to do If i want to use Redis ?

Answer (score 0):

There is redis support for Laravel

First you should [install](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis) redis server and start it as service.

**config/database.php**

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

**Usage example:**

```
\Cache::store('redis')->get('key', 'value', 10);
\Cache::store('redis')->get('key');
```

**Official Documentation:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/redis